$\lim_{n\to \infty } {\Huge [} {\frac{{}\sqrt[n]{2}+\sqrt[n]{3}+\sqrt[n]{5}}{3}\Huge ]}^{n} $
I encountered this limit and I failed, I need help with it:
$\lim_{n\to \infty }   {\Huge [}   {\frac{{}\sqrt[n]{2}+\sqrt[n]{3}+\sqrt[n]{5}}{3}\Huge ]}^{n} $=?
The answer they give is     $\sqrt[3]{30}$
My attempt is to try solve it for case  $1^{\infty }$ :
$\lim_{n\to \infty }   {\Huge [}   {\frac{{}\sqrt[n]{2}+\sqrt[n]{3}+\sqrt[n]{5}}{3}\Huge ]}^{n}=\lim_{n\to \infty }   {\Huge [}  1+ {\frac{{}\sqrt[n]{2}+\sqrt[n]{3}+\sqrt[n]{5}-3}{3}\Huge ]}^{\frac{3}{\sqrt[n]{2}+\sqrt[n]{3}+\sqrt[n]{5}-3}\frac{\sqrt[n]{2}+\sqrt[n]{3}+\sqrt[n]{5}-3}{3}n}
= e^{\lim_{n\longrightarrow \infty }\frac{n(\sqrt[n]{2}+\sqrt[n]{3}+\sqrt[n]{5}-3)}{3}}$
And now i tried to solve the :
$\lim_{n\to \infty }n(\sqrt[n]{2}+\sqrt[n]{3}+ \sqrt[n]{5}-3)$
Here i tried  Stolz–Cesàro( $\frac{\infty }{\infty }
$) with:
$(a_{n})_{n\ge 1} =\frac{1}{n}$
$(b_{n})_{n\ge 1} =\sqrt[n]{2}+\sqrt[n]{3}+\sqrt[n]{5}-3$
And got here
$\lim_{n\to \infty }n(n+1)(\sqrt[n]{2}+\sqrt[n]{3}+ \sqrt[n]{5}-\sqrt[n+1]{2}-\sqrt[n+1]{3}-\sqrt[n+1]{5})$
After that i was trying something with the formula : $\sqrt[n]{a}=e^{\frac{1}{n}lna}$ and got completed blocked

Does this answer your question? How to compute $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{a^{1/n}+b^{1/n}+c^{1/n}}3\right)^n$? - found using an Approach0 search. Note there are also other similar questions, e.g., with different numbers of terms, such as ...

(cont.) Limit of a sequence : and Calculate $\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac {\sqrt[n] 2 + \sqrt[n] 3} 2\right)^n$. Last, but not least, welcome to Math SE.

@JohnOmielan thank u for the site and response i got it
